# Looking for chat bubble icon in SVG format

Tags: images

I want to implement an iMessage like chat screen, and I need images like the two below. But in a flat style like what in iOS 9 Apple uses.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I know there are applications where images are data ... but this is just your looking for images to use as images.  I would think this would be better on webmasters or some other stack exchange site.  (if others agree, flag or vote to close, as if I do it, it'll be nuked immediately)

Comment: yeah i wasn't sure how to go about answering this, or if i should. i could see this getting extremely out of hand

Comment: It is on-topic, but János please say what kind of license you want. Are you OK with GNU-GPL-like, or with GNU-LGPL-like, or do you require public domain? Also, I guess you want stretchable parts to make the bubbles as large as you want, right? Or if you want just a fixed-size icon please tell us the desirable proportions.

Answer (score 3):

The Noun Project is my default open source imagery spot; although I don't see any that are 100%, some are pretty close, all are flat:
https://thenounproject.com/term/chat/2782/